# Flex Contextmenu doesn't show all items

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, show, visible

I created a contextmenu for my application.

```
if (!contextMenu) 
            {
                contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            }

            contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
            contextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT,onContextMenuSelected);

            _cmiEdit=new ContextMenuItem("Ändern");
            _cmiEdit.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,onContextMenuItemSelected);

            _cmiDelete=new ContextMenuItem("Löschen");
            _cmiDelete.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,onContextMenuItemSelected);


            contextMenu.customItems.push(_cmiEdit,_cmiDelete);
```

In the app only the first Contextmenuitem is visible and i can't figure out why?
In Air both are shown. Flashplayerversion 11.8

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug of the Flex! I tried to start your code with one more menu item "Über das Programm". The new item appeared! Then I tried to change the "ö" in Löschen with "oe" and it worked!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var _cmiEdit:ContextMenuItem;
            var _cmiDelete:ContextMenuItem;
            var _cmiAbout:ContextMenuItem;

            if (!contextMenu) 
            {
                contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            }

            contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
            contextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, onContextMenuSelected);

            _cmiEdit = new ContextMenuItem("Ändern");
            _cmiEdit.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, onContextMenuItemSelected);

            _cmiDelete=new ContextMenuItem("Loeschen");
            _cmiDelete.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, onContextMenuItemSelected);

            _cmiAbout=new ContextMenuItem("Über das Programm");
            _cmiAbout.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, onContextMenuItemSelected);


            contextMenu.customItems.push(_cmiEdit, _cmiDelete, _cmiAbout);
        }

        protected function onContextMenuSelected(evt:ContextMenuEvent):void
        {

        }

        protected function onContextMenuItemSelected(evt:ContextMenuEvent):void
        {

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```